# Does NodeJs and Redis make sense?

Tags: node.js, redis

NodeJS have a couple of caching npm modules. Does it make sense to use Redis for faster readings from cache? NodeJs is working in Memory. Same like Redis. I can't see any benefit to use Redis in combination with nodeJS.
Am i wrong?